# Adding an intermediate base class in a hierarchy of EF model entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

I have a model where there are two levels of inheritance, and two tables, more less like this:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public string FooA { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public string FooB { get; set; }
}

public class DX : B
{
    public string FooC { get; set; }
    public string FooDX { get; set; }
}

public class DY : B
{
    public string FooC { get; set; }
    public string FooDY { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<B>().ToTable("B", SchemaName);   // B table has columns FooA and FooB
modelBuilder.Entity<DX>().ToTable("DX", SchemaName); // DX table has columns FooC and FooDX
modelBuilder.Entity<DY>().ToTable("DY", SchemaName); // DY table has columns FooC and FooDY
```

This is working great. But over the time, DX and DY have grown to a point where they have multiple duplicated fields. I am looking for a way to refactor the common parts into a base class, something more less like this:

```
public abstract class C : B
{
    public string FooC { get; set; }
}

public class DX : B
{
    public string FooDX { get; set; }
}

public class DY : B
{
    public string FooDY { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot modify the database, but having a common class for DX and DY would make my life much easier. However, when I try this, I get the follwoing error:

> "Invalid column name 'Discriminator'. Invalid column name 'FooC'.

The "Discriminator" part makes me think Entity Framework is trying to query "C" from the "B" table instead of the "DX" and "DY" tables.

Is there a fix for this problem without modifying the database and keeping the three levels of inheritance?

**UPDATE:** I feel this should be fixed using [Table-Per-Concrete Class (TPC) Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.6), so I made `abstract` the classes I do not want to be mapped to a table and updated my model to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<B>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties();
    m.ToTable("B", SchemaName);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<DX>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties();
    m.ToTable("DX", SchemaName);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<DY>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties();
    m.ToTable("DY", SchemaName);
});
```

But then I get the following error:

> "The type 'DY' cannot be mapped as defined because it maps inherited properties from types that use entity splitting or another form of inheritance. Either choose a different inheritance mapping strategy so as to not map inherited properties, or change all types in the hierarchy to map inherited properties and to not use splitting. "